# Review-Overview is Slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Every now and then clicking on https://stackoverflow.com/review is extremely slow or not working at all. I assume that it has got something to do with recalculation or creating the aggregated data for the view?

Is there any chance to have us see a snapshot of the latest status while the new one is being calculated, i.e. make it fast?

Comment: That has a post on mSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229345/stack-overflow-review-button-is-slow-and-test-questions-are-slower

Comment: @rene Thanks. Too bad that I can't close this question as "The duplicate question must exist on Meta Stack Overflow" :(

Comment: Yes, I'm unsure if it should stay here or be migrated. OTH it is a problem that is due to the volume of SO maybe unique to SO. We will see. I'll wait until Tim Post has migrated questions from mSE back to here to see if that one becomes avialable here as a close target.

Comment: If you migrate it, it could be than closed as a duplicate. As a bonus, it can be double-voted.

Comment: Same problem from my side.It takes 15 seconds to show up.

Comment: @rene How can you consider this to be a double post being something about a current performance problem comparing it to an one year old question? Just for curiosity.

Comment: @FeliceM Hmmm, I didn't checked dates properly...I did know a recent post existed. I should have searched more carefully. I believe I posted the comment before I read the post from Tim Post that bugs can go anywhere so...this is a good marker question. Here is chat-bug-report http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1971349#1971349

Comment: For me both review and review-specific pages were horribly slow but it seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of July 18th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before/266018#266018), this should be resolved: the values are cached for a short period of time, and recalculated based on less stringent requirements when needed.

The numbers should still be *roughly* accurate most of the time, but for very fast-moving queues may appear when they should not.

Comment: Awesome!!!1! :)

Comment: @Shog9, this is very frustrating.  I finish reviewing a queue, hit review again, and see I have more to do, click on that, and then nothing appears.  Sometimes I finish 2 queues, then click on the number of the first queue finished, and nothing appears.

Comment: This should generally correct within 5 minutes, @Lance - go for coffee?