# Low Quality Review Queue is very slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

As well as [the /review page being slow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250104/review-overview-is-slow), the VLQ queue is also very slow. It generally takes between 14.24 and 14.98 seconds to load an item, but occasionally it takes up to 30 seconds. I think this is what is contributing to the size of the queue—which is currently at 76 items—because many people have probably stopped reviewing that queue. The only reason I haven't stopped reviewing is because I know that right now, with the queue being flooded, is when it is most important that I help with the reviews.

Surprisingly, the other queues seem to be fine (I don't know about the CVQ or RVQ, but I think they're okay).

Confirmed to happen in Firefox 28.0, Windows XP; and Chrome (latest), Windows 7.

Comment: CVQ doesn't look too bad...performance wise...

Comment: Also getting around 15-16 seconds from here.

Comment: I can't see the `VLQ` as I've done my day a few hours ago, but the slowness maybe has something to do with this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251218/cannot-access-the-review-page

Comment: On the CVQ in february I reported [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer). Your bug feels similar.

Comment: 23, 14, 14 seconds for me

Comment: ... this *might* have to do with them adding VLQ & NAA flags to the LQP queue. That means more things to query when showing review tasks.

Comment: ~20 seconds for me... First recognized it one or two days ago.

Comment: Seems like everyone got slow-banned. The queue is getting pretty big (relatively). Well, I did my 20 today (I'm patient), so just fix the problem and get more people reviewing.

Comment: This also has the side effect that the "tests if you're paying attention" can immediately be spotted because they load instantly.

Comment: As of today, this does not seem to be a problem anymore.

Comment: The audit posts have been taking a few seconds to load for the last few days -- don't even need to read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be fixed now, and the VLQ is down to reasonable levels again.