# The difference between low-quality vs unhelpful?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was going through the Low-Quality Review queue, and came across this instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5211983

I went ahead and chose the "Looks Good" response, because it did not match any of the pre-populated comments for deletion, and because it was an attempt at an answer.  It is simply wrong and unhelpful, so I then proceeded to vote and comment as such.

However, trying to read up on whether I took the correct action, I came across [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251820/what-are-the-criteria-for-low-quality-posts) in which Servy says in answer:

> If a post entered the queue due to a Not an Answer flag, but it is in
>   fact an answer, just a sufficiently low quality one to merit deletion,
>   then the improper flag shouldn't stop you from handling the post
>   appropriately

This would indicate that I should have clicked "Recommend Deletion."  Which would be the correct action?  Should I have instead done "Recommend Deletion" with no comment, then added my own comment as I did?

Edit: The answer has been improved, thankfully, but this question still stands per the case of the original answer, and any other such cases.

Comment: Related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the original revision was a really bad answer, I wouldn't say that it was an answer that merited deletion (certainly not by any of the criteria in the LQP queue, as you mentioned).  A downvote and optional comment is indeed the proper action for this post.

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation! My driving decision at the time was that, as a legitimate attempt at an answer, I figured it should remain alive, but be prompted for improvement. Voting can be reversed if it becomes a good answer, whereas if the user feels they cannot answer it, they can always delete it themselves. Deleting outright seemed to deny that chance entirely.