# Fix the "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." message

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Every post in the low quality posts review queue contains the following message

> This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and
>   content.

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251820/what-are-the-criteria-for-low-quality-posts):

> Once upon a time all of the posts in the queue were added
>   automatically based on a set of criteria. Since then, changes have
>   been made such that several types of flags are also directed into that
>   queue.

This (if true) suggests this message is a hold over from how this review queue used to work and is no longer accurate. Whatever the reason, the message currently adds no value. I suggest we take one of the following three actions.

- Give more information on the reason the post is in the review queue
- Remove it
- Replace it with a guide on how to use the queue (such as Help and Improvement has)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

> This (if true) suggests this message is a hold over from how this review queue used to work and is no longer accurate.

No, that's not true at all.  Both the message, and that quote, are accurate.  All of the posts in that queue have been flagged as low quality.  Some were flagged by people, and some were flagged automatically by the system.  You don't really need to know if it was flagged by a person or a robot; it doesn't change how you should evaluate the post.

Comment: If it's true that all posts are in the queue because of "length and content", why do long posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259551/3774582 (which is in my queue right now) show up in the queue? Should it be length *or* content? Or is it inaccurate? Either way, it's not a useful message, which is the perhaps more important point.

Comment: @Goose That's not a post that merits action from that queue.  You should be clicking "looks okay".  Who or what ever flagged it as having content problems *did so erroneously*, which is why that post doesn't actually have any problems meriting action from the queue.  Naturally not all posts you see in that queue will actually merit deletion.  *That's why there's a queue in the first place*.  If we already knew the post was bad and merited deletion, you wouldn't be asked to look at it, it would already be deleted.

Comment: I understand that. My point is only that the message is not useful. If it doesn't matter why it's in the queue, why claim it's in the queue because it was flagged because "length and content", especially in cases where the length is appropriate size and wasn't actually the reason it was flagged. At the *very* least, it could say "length *or* content", although length is a property of the content anyways, so why not just say "This answer has been flagged by users or criteria, review the post for issues that need editing or merit deletion" or something similiar?

Comment: @Goose Then why did you say it was inaccurate and outdated and should therefore be removed, if you actually recognize that it's entirely correct, you just want it to be worded more clearly (and if so, why not actually suggest the wording you think is better)?

Comment: I'm saying it's inaccurate. "length and content" implies length was an explicit reason it was flagged, but more accurate would be just "content", which is very vague anyways. In your original post, you say "changes have been made such that several types of flags are also directed into that queue.". Why not give more information on those reasons, rather than just saying "length and content"?

Comment: @Goose But it's *not* inaccurate.  Length is a major factor in the automated system's heuristics for determining if the post should go into the queue.  Sure, length is a part of the content, but by saying "length", it's being *less* vague than just saying "content" and nothing else.  As for why I said what I did in my other post, I *explain as much in that other post*.  Knowing more than that wouldn't be helpful.  There is nothing useful a reviewer can do with the information that it was flagged by a person or a bot; it doesn't change how they should review the post.